# (MySQL/PHP) Inserting data into MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I'm developing a web app for movie reviews. I am writing the page where reviews are created and am having issues with the data for a new review being uploaded to the MySQL database. When I submit a new review I get the created successfully message, however the database remains unchanged.

The POST data is gathered by forms located on the same page.

Connect.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('mydb');
if (!$select_db){
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("connect.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['critic_name'])){
$movie_id=NULL;      
if (isset($_POST['reviewmovie']) && isset($_POST['rating'])){
$movie_title = $_POST['reviewmovie'];
$review_title = $_POST['review_title'];
$movie_id = mysql_query("SELECT movie_id FROM Movies WHERE 'movie_title'=".$_POST['reviewmovie']." ") or die(mysql_error());       
$mem_id = mysql_query("SELECT mem_id FROM Members WHERE 'critic_name'=".$_SESSION['critic_name']." ") or die(mysql_error());
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$result = mysql_num_rows($movie_id);
$result2 = mysql_num_rows($mem_id);
if(!$result && !$result2){
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Reviews` (review_id, rating, comments, mem_id movie_id, review_title) VALUES ('$rating', '$comments', '$mem_id', '$movie_id', '$review_title')");
if($query){
$msg = "Review Created Successfully.";
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from both `WHERE 'movie_title'` and `WHERE 'critic_name'` those are column names and not variables. Plus change `".$_POST['reviewmovie']."` to `'".$_POST['reviewmovie']."'` and `".$_SESSION['critic_name']."` to `'".$_SESSION['critic_name']."'`

Comment: Please, before you get yourself into trouble, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this. **Never** put `$_POST` data directly in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from both `WHERE 'movie_title'` and `WHERE 'critic_name'` those are column names and not variables. If you *absolutely* want to wrap them in something, use backticks `` `.

Plus, change `".$_POST['reviewmovie']."` to `'".$_POST['reviewmovie']."'` and `".$_SESSION['critic_name']."` to `'".$_SESSION['critic_name']."'`

You also forgot a comma in between `mem_id` and `movie_id` (which will break your query).

```
(review_id, rating, comments, mem_id movie_id, review_title)
                                    ^ // <- right there
```

Change it to:

```
(review_id, rating, comments, mem_id, movie_id, review_title)
```

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to use mysqli_* functions in the future. I changed everything you recommended. Still doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: You're welcome. Check to see if `$_SESSION['critic_name']` is indeed set and not empty by doing `var_dump($_SESSION['critic_name']);` if it shows up empty/NULL then that's another problem because your entire query is based on whether the session is set. @user3491695

Comment: Also, these are other conditional statements that your query is relying on `(isset($_POST['reviewmovie']) && isset($_POST['rating'])` are your form elements named and no spelling mistakes? Letter-case is also important. `name="reviewmovie"` and `name="ReviewMovie"` are not the same. Double check everything. Even if ONE is mispelled or has a missing `name="something"`, your query will fail. @user3491695